# Angular 2 HTTP is not working

Tags: google-maps, angular, geocode

I am using Angular 2 beta.18, and trying to use google map geocode.
I am doing the same as all tutorial describe, but I receive a strange response.

My component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

convertAddressToCooredinate(address: string){
  if(address != null){
    var address ="1334 Emerson St, NE Washington DC";
    return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(address))
                    .map(response => response.json());  
    }
  }
}
```

The response should contain a JSON with results, however I recieve the following:

*Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}*

I tried directing the request to other URLs and receive the same response.

Comment: Where do you subscribe to this observable?

Comment: Why are you not updating. Beta 18 is very old.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer maybe I am mistaken, I created a project a week ago using Angular-cli. the read me file says version 1.0.0-beta.18.

Comment: That's probably angular-cli beta.18 but Angular 2.1, so it should be fine.

Comment: @echonax I did not used it, I just deleted it and it still response the same.

Comment: If you don't subscribe to this observable you won't make a rest call to your backend. Hence you log only your observable. Can you add where exactly you are logging this Observable {_isScalar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertAddressToCooredinate` function returns an observable. If you don't subscribe to this observable in your code, you won't make a rest call to your backend. Hence you log only your observable.

Example:

```
Some Component
constructor(private gms: GoogleMapService ) { 
    this.gms.convertAddressToCooredinate('some address')
        .subscribe((response)=>{
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DanaEzer Glad I could help